# client side validation through jquery

Tags: jquery

i have form like this , i need to validate through jquery, i have tried many methods codes for this , all are done by based id , here i dont have id , if i create a id , it will show error, how can i solve this issue .

my requirement is if user clicked sign in without filling field , is should show  error like please enter username and password.

Thank you in advance.

```
<form asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Authenticate" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="username" name="Username" class=" form-control" placeholder="Enter your username id">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class=" form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      
   
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
       </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the jquery you tried that worked when using an `id`.   It might just be a case of changing `#id` to `.class`

Comment: @RyanWilson seems OP can get it to work with an `id` - so "it will show error" = "it will show [the validation] error" rather than "it will show [an] error".  But it's still unclear from what's been provided just *why* that is the case.

Comment: @freedomn-m Oh, now I see what they are saying. Thank you.